# What a lonely f prime means?

Tags: notation

Here the different equations that form part of the process:

$W=Pf(N)$

$W=P^eg(N)$

$Y=Y(N)$

$Y'=f(N)$

$z = \left( \array{dN \\ dP\\ dP^e} \right)$

$dP^e=\gamma dP$

Here is the whole process:

$Pf(N)=P^eg(N)$

$\nabla \phi(N,P,P^e) = \left( \array{Pf'(N) - P^e g'(N)\\ f(N)\\ -g(N)} \right)$

$\nabla \phi(N,P,P^e) \cdot z = Pf'(N)-P^eg'(N))dN+f(N)dP-g(N)dP^e$

$\nabla \phi(N,P,P^e) \cdot z = (Pf'(N)-P^eg'(N))dN+f(N)dP-g(N)dP^e$

$Pf'dN+f(N)dP=P^eg'dN+g(N)dP^e$

$Pf'dN+f(N)dP=P^eg'dN+g(N)\gamma dP$

$f(N)dP-g(N) \gamma dP=P^e g'dN-Pf'dN$

In Equilibrium $f(N)=g(N)$, therefore:

$(1- \gamma)f(N)dP=(P^eg'-Pf')dN$

$dN=\frac {f(N)(1-\gamma)}{(p^eg'-Pf')}dP$

This exercise keeps going but at this point now I have a $g'$ and a $f'$ that looks that are treated as variables, but I for some reason can't interpret f or g prime is right afterward I don't have $(N)$.

Comment: Huh?  "trough [sic] some differentiation I end up with $f$ and ($x$) separated."  What can that *possibly* mean??

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I *think* he is asking about the difference between $f$ or $f'$ and $f(x)$ or $f'(x)$. No idea what differentiation has to do with it though.

Comment: It looks like they just skipped writing "$(N)$" to save space. This is very common in Differential Equations.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is a function.

$f'$ means the derivative of $f$, which is also a function.

$f(x)$ means $f$ evaluated at $x$.

$f'(x)$ means $f'$ evaluated at $x$.